# For an alphabet of size $N$, how many strings have all of its substrings of length $\geq 2$ unique?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

For an alphabet of $N$ characters, how many strings can be formed (including the empty string) so that no substring of length $\geq 2$ appears more than once in the string? The maximum length of such a string is quadratic in $N$ (easy to see). However that still leads to an exoponential search space of total strings in terms of $N$. A formula would be preferred (even if it's a summation or something), but if there is also an algorithmic trick to compute the number of satisfying strings for fairly decent $N$ using a computer, that would also be acceptable.

Bonus Question: Instead of substrings of length $2$, what if we have an alphabet of size $N$ and we want to know how many strings have no repeated substrings of length $k$?

Comment: This is probably very difficult.  I would write some code to compute the sequence by brute force and then check the OEIS.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to look into [De Bruijn sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence); it sounds like you want to count the distinct non-self-intersecting paths through the De Bruijn graph.

Comment: There is an explicit formula count for number of Debruijn sequences but they assume that the sequence is cyclic and that every subsequence of a particular length (e.g. two in my case) occurs exactly once. This is certainly a lower bound for what I want to count, but I don't see how to count the remaining sequences that are either shorter or have every subsequence occurring only once without being cyclic sequences.

Comment: Agreed that it's not a solution out of the box; but I'm wondering if (a) every sequence you want to count is a subsequence of a DeBruijn sequence; and (b) is it possible to think about your desired sequences can always be thought of as a walk through some sub-graph of the De Bruijn graph (albeit, not necessarily a Hamiltonian path).